# How to import another "app" into my next-project?

Tags: merge, next.js

I am building my very first react/next.js-page.

Time is short and I would like to cut some corners if possible.

You can find it on the master-branch of this repo: https://github.com/ehak123/SpeedDating

I want to add a simple login/registration-form and found this great "how-to-guide" online. It really looks sleak. The code for the finished login/reg-form is found on this repo: https://github.com/cornflourblue/next-js-11-registration-login-example

How do I in a simple way import this into my own project?

I have tried to "merge" the two projects in so many ways but keep hitting into problems. I searched the web for help, but cant really find any. I figure: it must exist an easier way, like a custom way to do this?

Comment: The best way is to manually merge and update the projects into one because they both use different file structures, versions of Next, naming conventions, markdown, etc.  Merging two projects will take knowledge of Next, React, JS, and CSS.

Comment: Oh my. I have tried for several days now. :(

Comment: I seem to get some thing to work but some not